# Swift 4 Decodable: Decoding complex JSON

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, codable, decodable

I have to decode an array of the dictionary, where the key is an enum & value is a model object.

Here is my sample JSON,

```
[
  {
    "nanomp4": {
      "url": "https://media.tenor.com/videos/a1da4dcf693c2187615721d866decf00/mp4", 
      "dims": [
        150, 
        138
      ], 
      "duration": 2.0, 
      "preview": "https://media.tenor.com/images/17d523e6b7c3c9a4ca64566a1890d94d/tenor.png", 
      "size": 70381
    }, 
    "nanowebm": {
      "url": "https://media.tenor.com/videos/aa983425114e32ab446f669d91611938/webm", 
      "dims": [
        150, 
        138
      ], 
      "preview": "https://media.tenor.com/images/17d523e6b7c3c9a4ca64566a1890d94d/tenor.png", 
      "size": 53888
    }, 
  },
  {
    "nanomp4": {
    "url": "https://media.tenor.com/videos/a1da4dcf693c2187615721d866decf00/mp4",
    "dims": [
          150,
          138
          ],
    "duration": 2.0,
    "preview": "https://media.tenor.com/images/17d523e6b7c3c9a4ca64566a1890d94d/tenor.png",
    "size": 70381
    },
  }
]
```

Here is my decoding code,

```
do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let collection = try decoder.decode([[GIFFormat:Media]].self, from: data)

    print(collection)
} catch {
    print("Error in parsing/decoding JSON: \(error)")
}
```

Here `GIFFormat` is Enum & `Media` is the model object, and they are decoding perfectly fine.

```
enum GIFFormat: String, Decodable {

    case nanoMP4    = "nanomp4"
    case nanoWebM   = "nanowebm"
}

struct Media: Decodable {
    let url: URL?        
    let dims: [Int]?
    let duration: Double?
    let preview: URL?
    let size: Int64?
}
```

My console prints,

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

Can anyone explain to me what is exactly wrong here?

Comment: add some code, how you're decoding your JOSN

Comment: The error is quite clear. As it says `Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.`

Comment: @Malik That is the question, why is it still expecting `Any`, when I have specified format.

Comment: It's not the `Any` that's causing the issue. It's `Array` vs `Dictionary`. Can you share the code for `GIFFormat` and `Media`?

Comment: @Malik Added structs. Also, `Any` could be a `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the `rawValue` for `GIFFormat` is `String`, `GIFFormat` itself is an enum. You should update

```
let collection = try decoder.decode([[GIFFormat:Media]].self, from: data)
```

to

```
let collection = try decoder.decode([[GIFFormat.RawValue:Media]].self, from: data)
```

**UPDATE:** In response to your comment

> Now to access value, I need to use like this,
>   `collection?.first?[GIFFormat.mp4.rawValue]?.url`. Which is again ugly
>   !!

I would suggest a bit of refactoring. You can start by removing your `enum` altogether. Keep your `Media` struct. Create a new `Collection` struct

```
struct Collection: Decodable {
    let nanomp4: Media!
    let nanowebm: Media!
}
```

Then, you can update the above line to

```
let collection = try decoder.decode([Collection].self, from: data)
```

and your **ugly** line transforms into

```
collection.first?.nanomp4.url
```

**NOTE:** This solution assumes that you only have `nanomp4` & `nanowebm` as your enum values. If this is not the case, then this might not be the best solution and you might have to go with the first solution.

Comment: Not to access value, I need to use like this, `collection?.first?[GIFFormat.mp4.rawValue]?.url`. Which is again ugly !!

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is exactly what was my previous implementation. :-). Hope, the further versions of Swift makes enum & codable more smart. ;-)